# Retrieving Only File Name from a Directory

Tags: c#

Using Directory class library I am trying to retrieve all files Name existing in a Folder as below:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"d:\Images\", "*.png");
        foreach (string img in filePaths)
        {
          listBox1.Items.Add(img.ToString());
        }
    }
```

As you know this method returns Full path and name of the file but I need to get ONLY the name of files.Is it possible to do this in Directory Class? Do I have to use the Path class for this? if yes, how I can assign a path to a variable without file name?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
using System.IO;

...

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"d:\Images\", "*.png"); 
    foreach (string img in filePaths) 
    { 
        listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(img)); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method

```
var file = Path.GetFileName(img);
```

Comment: Hi Candie, Thanks for comment but how I can implement your hint inside my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path,searchpattern);`

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\roberth\Programming_Projects\Common\UI\bin\Debug\",
                                                 "*.xml");
            var filename = new List<string>();
            Console.WriteLine("Parsing Files...");
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                filename.Add(file);
                Console.WriteLine("Parsing file: " + file);
                ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DirectoryInfo` instead of `Directory`.  It returns a `FileInfo` which you can get the `Name` property of.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    var filePaths = new DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(@"d:\Images\", "*.png").Select(x => x.Name);
    foreach (string img in filePaths)
    {
      listBox1.Items.Add(img.ToString());
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN

```
string fileName = @"C:\mydir\myfile.ext";
string path = @"C:\mydir\";
string result;

result = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    fileName, result);

result = Path.GetFileName(path);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    path, result);

// This code produces output similar to the following: 
// 
// GetFileName('C:\mydir\myfile.ext') returns 'myfile.ext' 
// GetFileName('C:\mydir\') returns ''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string aPath= @"course\train\yes\";
var fileNames=Directory.GetFiles(aPath).Select(name=>Path.GetFileName(name)).ToArray();
```